# PURE-ftpd + passive mode + TLS

Tags: ftp, tls, passive

I have got linux (debian 7.1 wheezy ), where I run pure-ftpd, created virtual users, folder for ftp. I also install openssl, create private certificate for tls. All seems good.

- When user connect from internal address in passive mode without TLS - its working fine.
- When user connect from internal address in passive mode with TLS - its working fine.
- When user connect from external address in passive mode without TLS - its working fine.
- When user connect from external address in passive mode with TLS - ftp doesn't work, because ftp server return to external client local ip address. And client doens't know this address.

I also tried solve this problem to create conf file in `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ForcePassiveIP`, where is written external address. But when user connect from external address he got external address what is fine, but after he got another error with connection. And I think this is not good, because users from internal network will not be able to connect ftp, because they will get external address from ForcePassiveIP conf file.

Maybe I can make two ftps server with different settings, but I think its not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '30000 50000' > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange
$ service pure-ftpd restart
```

Also if you use CSF or iptables you need to open all ports from 30000 to 50000.